# How can I use a Panel as a Region in Prism?

Tags: wpf, prism, panel

The prism documentation states that there are three region adapters available:

> **ContentControlRegionAdapter**. This adapter adapts controls of type `System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl` and derived classes.
>
> **SelectorRegionAdapter**. This adapter adapts controls derived from the class `System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector`, such as the `System.Windows.Controls.TabControl` control.
>
> **ItemsControlRegionAdapter**. This adapter adapts controls of type `System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl` and derived classes.

Unfortunately, `Panel` does not fall into any of those categories, and I want to be able to write this in my `.xaml.cs`:

```
<Canvas cal:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static local:RegionNames.MainCanvas}">
```

How can we accomplish this?

Comment: The problem here is that a canvas doesn't impose any layout.  You are going to run into problems unless you make your regionadapter a little more intelligent about placement of the elements that are registered with that region (this is also why Panel is not supported).  I'm curious... what application do you have for this?

Comment: I'm updating an existing codebase that has floating control containers (like toolbars) that expect to be inside a Canvas. They handle their own "title bar" region and update their canvas position on drag. Obviously this could be accomplished in other ways, but, as always, time is of the essence and this seems to be the fastest way I can convert the existing structure to work with Prism.

Comment: Having a control update its position seems a little illogical... sort of "getting outside your box".  +1 for being able to convert existing codebase.

Comment: I totally agree. Given time, they should probably be moved to Windows (or maybe even Popups). I just don't see the time being available right now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this can be found in this very nice, [descriptive blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20200927042327/http://geekswithblogs.net/JeffFerguson/archive/2009/06/30/working-with-prism-and-the-blacklight-controls.aspx).

However, I want the answer stored on StackOverflow as well :) It took a bit of searching to get this from Google. Here is my code that works with a basic Panel.

**Step 1 - create a new region adapter**

```
public class PanelHostRegionAdapter : RegionAdapterBase<Panel>
{
    public PanelHostRegionAdapter(IRegionBehaviorFactory behaviorFactory)
        : base(behaviorFactory)
    {
    }

    protected override void Adapt(IRegion region, Panel regionTarget)
    {
        region.Views.CollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
               {
                   if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
                   {
                       foreach (FrameworkElement element in e.NewItems)
                       {
                           regionTarget.Children.Add(element);
                       }
                   }
                   else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
                   {
                       foreach (FrameworkElement CurrentElement in e.OldItems)
                           regionTarget.Children.Remove(CurrentElement);
                   }
               };
    }

    protected override IRegion CreateRegion()
    {
        return new AllActiveRegion();
    }
}
```

**Step 2 - update your bootstrapper**

```
public class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
       ...
    }

    protected override IModuleCatalog GetModuleCatalog()
    {
       ...
    }

    protected override RegionAdapterMappings ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings()
    {
        RegionAdapterMappings Mappings = base.ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings();
        Mappings.RegisterMapping(typeof(Panel), Container.Resolve<PanelHostRegionAdapter>());
        return Mappings;
    }
}
```